# How do we define a complete metric on a Riemann surface with punctures?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

This question is related to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192029/riemann-surface-with-punctures-corresponds-to-a-hyperbolic-surface-with-cusps%22another%20question%22).

If we have a Riemann surface with punctures of negative Euler characterstisc, how can one define a complete hyperbolic metric?

I know that in this case the universal cover is the hyperbolic plane and it has a complete metric. Do we project this metric to the puntured surface? If so, why is it complete?

I will deeply appreciate if somebody gives an example or a good reference.